# How to use blockchain as a Database?

Tags: blockchain, blocks, database

I'm pretty new to the concept of blockchain and use cases so please bear with me if this sounds to vague or elementary. 
As, I researched more on this, I wanna know how can we use blockchain as a database. Per se, I have product prices database, which contains product price, details and other meta data. The prices of products might change, depending on the product owner. I want to know how to design a solution based on blockchain to store this information and disseminate the updates in near real time. How and where the block-chain will reside ?

Update:
Let's say I'm the owner of a company whose provides IT Products to it's clients. Each client can have different price for the same product based on the pre-signed contracts. Product details are currently stored in a database(lets name it `Back_DB`)(details defined below)

1. Product_id
2. Price
3. Type
4. Description

This database is located in different location which I have limited/no access to. I have a database on my side(lets name it `FrontDB`), which I use to show the prices and details of each products to the clients. I get the updates in the form of data dump from the `BackDB` to `FrontDB` once in a day at a defined time. Here comes my use case. 
I want to use blockchain concepts and create an architecture such that as soon as there is an update/deletion/creation of product info in the `BackDB` it is communicated to my `FrontDB` in the form of a transaction in a block, so that it always contains newest information.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: hey, updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to start is to understand the following few concepts and learnings.

1. what is Smart contracts ?
2. What is solidity and how to start writing your domain data or objects in solidity.
3. Understand event logging, to store searchable data , and how to use it.

Be aware your questions is too broad.But this three points will answer your most practical requirements.

I am working on this one currently , it is a bloodbank scenario ( most simplest )  and a work in progress, uses event logging. [Read up](http://www.bullraider.com/ethereum/tutorials) and code base for the application part of it is [here](https://github.com/The-Neo-Noir/BloodbankEventDapp)
There is a tweeter app written by http://ethertweet.net/ which will give you some idea.

Please **DON'T** expect community to design and code for you. Do some ground work, Community will back you up.

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply. I know about smart contracts, but will start looking into solidity and event logging. I have updated the question with more details. I don't expect any design or code help from the community. But my case is, thus this kind of scenario makes sense in blockchain perspective. If yes, how to go about it(as you have mentioned the concepts :)